# NodeJS vs Golang Performance

Tags: optimization

I was testing performance of NodeJS vs GoLang with a very simple script. Situation one is three nested for loops to do a Sin calculation and Situation two is just one for loop.

It turns out that for three for loops, NodeJS is much faster (about 3 times), but for one for loop Go is much faster (about 3 times as well). Can someone explains how this time difference originates and any suggestions on how to improve the performance of the 3 nested for loops in GoLang?

This is the NodeJS code:

```
situation=2;
//set situation to either 1 or to 2;
if (situation==1) {
    for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<1000; j++) {
            for (var k=0; k<1000; k++) {
                Math.sin(i*j*k);
            }
        }
    }   
} else {
    for (var i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
        Math.sin(i);
    }   
}
```

and this is the equivalent GoLang code:

```
package main

import (
    "math"
)

func main() {
// set situation to either 1 or to 2    
situation :=2
    if situation == 1 {
        var i,j,k float64;
        for k=0; k<1000; k++ {
            for j=0; j<1000; j++ {
                for i=0; i<1000; i++ {
                    math.Sin(i*j*k);
                }       
            }       
        }
    } else if situation == 2 {
        var i float64;
        for i=0; i<100000000; i++ {
            math.Sin(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insights!